# Clicking reset in Views UI causes PDOException Error

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I have a searchable view created that returns the following error when I click to  "reset" the search query. It only occurs when resetting a search from the search terms field.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500.

The logs show the following:

> PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances in
>   DrupalDatabaseCache->set() (line 455 of /code/includes/cache.inc).

This error occurs in the preview, not on the live page.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://www.drupal.org/node/1372376#comment-8459391

Comment: Thanks @j-reynolds but, unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. The error still occurs.

Comment: View on its own does not do this so it must be a contrib module that is to fault. If you find the offending module like @Clive suggests then post a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Something is trying to serialise a PDO object, which you can't do in PHP (unless you're running < 5.3 and are happy with nasty workarounds).

Drupal core doesn't do this; The Views module itself doesn't do this; so you'll need to disable custom/contributed modules you have installed one by one until you find the culprit. If/when you do, either fix the module if custom, or report the bug to the module's issue queue on Drupal.org for review.

If you're making use of the PHP filter in that View, remove the PHP code temporarily to see if that's the problem. If it is, consider re-implementing that logic in a more stable manner, i.e. using the hooks from the Views module.

Comment: Thanks again @clive but, unfortunately, none of your suggestions fixed the issue. I'll keep hunting.